# How to stop acorn-head supply tube from leaking?

Tags: leak, faucet, pipe, sink

The purple highlighted rectangle shows the spot where the acorn-head supply tube connects to the faucet valve.  Ours is leaking, no matter how tight it is, and even after applying teflon to the grooves.

Is it alright to apply teflon to the head of the acorn/male portion of the supply tube?  I'm not sure what else to try.

[image]

Comment: Check to ensure the threads are not stripped and that the pipe has not been deformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the compression nut is tight, then you should not have a leak.  dont put teflon on a compression joint face.  you can, if desperate pull it apart and coat everything with a good layer of pipe dope and then reassemble.  sometimes you may have a little corroded pore that this can fix.  might be time to replace the supply line, nut and ferrule.  other possibilities:

1) its not leaking from the supply connection.  in these setups, its sometimes hard to diagnose where the leak is due to access issues.  check the compression nut on the cross connection.  they often work themselves loose and cause a tiny leak that wicks down the threads of the valve body and makes it appear the leak is coming from the supply line connection.

2)  valve body itself could be cracked or leaking from one of the valve bushing nuts up above.  same logic as 1)

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I might need to replace the supply line.  I was hoping to save it because it's copper and the rest of the sink is all copper.  I didn't know how much it would be to find another copper replacement (or how easy it would be to cut it to the right size/shape).

Comment: not sure if you are trying to preserve the copper for aesthetic reasons or not, but there is nothing superior about it functionally.   a simple flexible supply line with inner rubber hose and outer stainless braid is the norm nowadays.  much safer as it remains able to absorb vibration and thermal expansion better than solid metal.